# Python String of Hex to Hex (with leading zeros)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, hex

I have some issue with hex conversion in Python.

I have a string that represents a hex number - `"02"` and I want to convert it to `0x02` and to join it to another hex number.

My code:

```
valToWrite1 = '\x3c'
valToWrite2 = '02'
```

I want to join those 2 values so that my result will be `"\x3c\x02"`.
It's important to keep the leading zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`binascii.unhexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify("02")
'\x02'
>>> '\x3c' + _
'<\x02'
```